# I needed to make a script that sends emails seen as another person

Tags: php

My Professor assigned me to send him an email from Facebook that says his profile is been shut down. He will then reply to me with something, how can I see his reply?

I basically need to forward his message to me. Is that possible?
Thanks in advance.

```
$to = "to emial pou thesn a to steileis vazeis edw"; 
$subject = "kanonika subject sto email";
$message = "mnm"
$from = "email pou thes na fainetai oti stalthike"; 
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$mail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$from);  
if($mail)  { echo "Email sent to ".$to; } ?>
```

Ignore whatever is inside "", it's just something to make it better for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just looking for the "from" and "reply-to" headers?  Not sure what you mean by "forward his message to me".

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but you might be asking for `Reply-To:`.

Comment: Spoof the "from" in your reply headers.

Comment: Sorry for that, i am pretty new to coding altogether. Yeah basically looking for the reply to. Like when someone goes on to reply to the email he just received, the message he replied will be forwarded to another email so i can actually see what he typed.